# How to fix "IndexError: list index out of range" error of p2p chat application on Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming, tcpclient, p2p

I am doing p2p chat application by Python. There is a error at 
"message = inputt[1]" on client side. Because of this error when i want to send message the program prints "You must write your name "

I dont know how to solve because i didnt understand the logic of the mistake. It will be great if i can get the explanation of why i am getting this error and the solution.

```py
import socket
import json
import time
import threading
import datetime

onlineUsers = dict()

while True:

    message = input()

    if(message=='list'):
        print('ONLINE USERS...')
        for key in onlineUsers:
            print(key)

    else:

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        port=5001


        try:
            inputArray = message.split(':',1)
            # 0=username  1=message
            username=inputArray[0]
            message=inputArray[1]
            ip=onlineUsers[username]
            s.connect((ip, port))
            s.sendall(message)

        except:
            print("You must write your name <name: message >")

        s.close()
```

Comment: What is the output when you do `print(inputArray)` ?

Comment: I wrote " this is a test " as message and the output was "   ['this is a test']   "

Comment: Got it, thanks @buchic , see if my answer below helps you!

Comment: Thank you so much @DeveshKumarSingh for your effort. Actually I have some couple of questions more. I texted you through LinkedIn. Could you please check it?

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help :) please mark the answeeras accepted if it helped you @buchic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the clue to what went wrong is in the question itself. The print statement says `"You must write your name <name: message >"`, so your message will be `john : this is a test`, but instead you are sending `this is a test`, which when you split on `:` will give you a single element list `['this is a test']` and when you try to get the second index of this list, you get the `IndexError: list index out of range`

So if you fix your message to match the format expected, the code should work as follows

```
message = 'john : this is a test'
inputArray = message.split(':')
# 0=username  1=message
username = inputArray[0].strip()
message = inputArray[1].strip()
print(username)
print(message)
```

The output will be

```
john
this is a test
```